# How to show all servers in PgAdmin III LTS by BigSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-bigsql

Postgres PgAdmin server pane contains lot of servers.

BigSQL Postgres 10.1 was installed in Windows 10. It installed also PgAdmin III LTS by BigSQL.

In this PgAdmin server window only servers added in it are shown. For example, if server named testbigsqlsever is added, BigSQL pgAdmin shows it:

[image]

How to force it to show also servers installed by earlier PgAdmin III ? Earlier pgAdmin remains also in this computer and it shows all servers.

It looks like both pgadmins store server list in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers
```

but  PgAdmin III LTS by BigSQL does not show servers added by standard pgAdmin.

Since standard pgAdmin does not support Postgres 10 and pgAdmin IV does not have config editors and has poor user interface BigSQL pgAdmin should used. There are number of servers added earlier and manually adding them all requires lot of work

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: pgAdmin is open source product like Postgres itself. SO contains lot of questions and answers about Postgres and PgAdmin.

Comment: SO is for questions directly related to programming problems. Your question is about administering a Postgres DB using pgAdmin - that's off topic here. Please read [what topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Note that your question is an exact fit for Server Fault.

Comment: If it is so why SO contains PgAdmin tag? pgAdmin is administering application widely used by programmers like me, not only administrators. According to your comment please remove pgAdmin tag, all related questions and answers from SO. If pgAdmin tag is present, pgAdmin questions should accepted.

Comment: Tags can be created by users, it doesn't mean that the tags are on-topic (there's a special process for deleting for this very reason). The site rules still apply as to what's on-topic. That said, I guess I could look into raisin an issue on Meta to blacklist the tag and if possible migrating the questions.